# Converting Simplifed Chinese GB 2312 text characters into UTF8

Tags: c++, unicode, internationalization

How do I convert text between multi-byte text strings, for example Simplified Chinese GB 2312, into UTF8 using c++ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On unix systems you'd best use the iconv library.

See [iconv_open](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/iconv_open/), [iconv](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/iconv/), [iconv_close](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/iconv_close/)

You'd have to know the character encoding of course (EUC-CN, HZ).

If not on a unix system, search for some support in the OS, doing character conversions by hand is very hard to get right.

Answer (score 2):

WinAPI: [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776413(VS.85).aspx) and vice versa, [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776420(VS.85).aspx).
I can post a sample later.

However, UTF-8 is rather tricky to represent and more specifically, to use, in applications. The MultiByteToWideChar function converts a string to [UTF-16 (UCS2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2). I suggest you use this format in your software internally, and only convert it to UTF-8 using WideCharToMultiByte if your program needs to produce such output. This is the standard way of doing internationalization/unicode on Windows & OS X.